# A moderator - Caleb - asked me to recreate the question. Now what?

Tags: discussion

I asked this question. [***How are Lutheran weekday “prayer services” different from “matins” or “vespers”?***](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/30371/how-are-lutheran-weekday-prayer-services-different-from-matins-or-vespers) The problem was, that question was an edit on a closed question, because the earlier closed question was too broad. So, a moderator - Caleb - suggested that I should recreate the question, and [I did](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/30460/how-are-lutheran-weekday-prayer-services-different-from-matins-or-vespers). Now what? Will the previous question be closed now as a duplicate instead of "too broad"? Will it be deleted?

Comment: you should link to the questions in question

Comment: I questioned that myself.  Which questions are the questions in question?

Comment: All I have left are questions now.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a duplicate. The two questions are quite different—that is why I suggested asking it as a separate question in the first place. Answers to one are not ever remotely compatible with the other.

To make it clear what the state is and why it was closed I have reverted the original to the original version. This is what the answers are targeted toward. Unfortunately this question is too broad, and as put it will stay closed as too broad. Eventually if nobody thinks of a way to make it narrow enough without completely changing the question it will likely be deleted.